# Number Input Field Keeps Increasing after e.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, preventdefault

Listening to a 'click' event on an input element with type="number" and if the `e.currentTarget.value` is greater than a certain value I would like to stop the input from increasing.

I used `e.preventDefault()` however the input continues to increase value. I also tried `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` and the input continued to increase the value. I also check the value of `e.cancelable` and it is true. Also when logging the event, the properties `isDefaultPrevented` and `isPropagationStopped` are both true.

Another solution I tried was to just set the value of the input back to the old value but then for a split second it changed, which is undesirable.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
// @method setFocus sets focus on input when clicked. Needed as FF won't focus if quantity is updated from spinners
// @return {Void}
,   setFocus: function setFocus (e)
{

    var value = parseInt(e.currentTarget.value, 10)
    , qty_avail = this.model.getStockInfo().stock
    , $input_quantity = this.$('[name="quantity"]');

    if(value > qty_avail)
    {

        e.preventDefault();
        this.$('.product-details-quantity-alert').html("There is only " + qty_avail + " piece(s) available with these options");
        this.$('.product-details-quantity-alert').css("display", "initial");

    }
    else
    {
        this.$('.product-details-quantity-alert').css("display", "none");
        $input_quantity.focus();
    }

    console.log(qty_avail);
    console.log(value);

}
```

Comment: could you explain *if the* `e.currentTarget.value` *is greater than a certain value I would like to stop the input from increasing.* you mean prevent the user from being able to increase it, or is the input somehow increasing automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input type="number" has *max* and *min* attribute that can be set, you can set the *max* attribute to constrain the element from increasing beyond a specified number. This can be achieved using HTML as below

```
<input id="quantity" type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="100" >
```

You can also update the *max* attribute on the fly using javascript (for example the javascript code below changes max to 90)

```
document.getElementById("quantity").setAttribute("max",90);
```

Consider the third option below

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" />

<script>
var myinput = $("#quantity")

myinput.on('input',restrictMax)
function restrictMax(){
    //set Maximum to 5
    var max = 5;
    var value = parseFloat($(this).val())
    if($(this).val() > max){
        $(this).val(max)
    }
 }
</script>
```

You can also check the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/91142/)

Hope this helps

Comment: I wanted to avoid using those attributes. Is it impossible to do without using them? The reason being is that I then have to expose model data to a module in our site which could affect performance

Comment: Kindly check the updated answer with the 3rd option using jquery. It uses the _on input_ option